# How to make password field null in update page yii2

Tags: php, forms, yii2

Hello I am working on Yii2 project. I have user module, in that while update any user the input filed password is coming with original password. I want to make password field null on update page.

I am using password hash, but in update page password coming with its original value, I tried to null that filed but with bad luck.

I tried :

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'password_hash')->passwordInput(['maxlength' => true,'value'=>null]) ?>
```

**Even I tried**
`$model->password_hash=""` in controller but nothing happen.

But nothing happen still password field coming with its value.

**This is my user model rules :**

```
public function rules() {
        return [
            [['first_name', 'last_name', 'address', 'mobile', 'email', 'password_hash', 'role_id'], 'required'],
            [['address'], 'string'],
            [['role_id'], 'integer'],
            [['email'], 'email'],
            [['email'], 'unique', 'targetAttribute' => ['email']],
            [['created_at', 'updated_at'], 'safe'],
            [['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password_hash'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['mobile'], 'required','on'=>'create,update'],
            //[['mobile'], 'string','max'=>10],
            [['mobile'], 'number','numberPattern' => '/^[0-9]{10}$/','message'=>"Mobile must be integer and should not greater then 10 digit"],
            [['password_hash'],'string','min'=>6],
            //[['mobile'], 'number'],
            [['status'], 'string', 'max' => 1,'on'=>'create,update'],
            [['role_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Roles::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['role_id' => 'id']],
        ];
    }
```

**User controller :**

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);
        $roles= Roles::find()->all();
        $model->password_hash="";
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            $input=Yii::$app->request->post();
            if($input['Users']['password_hash']!=""){
                $model->password_hash=User::setPassword($model->password_hash);
            }
            //$model->auth_key=User::generateAuthKey();
            $model->status=$input['Users']['status'];
            unset($model->created_at);
            $model->updated_at=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                //echo "<pre>";print_r($model);exit;

            $model->save();
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', "Record has been updated successfully !");
            //return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
            return $this->redirect(['index']);
        } else {
            return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,
                'roles'=>$roles
            ]);
        }
    }
```

**User Form :**

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <?= $form->field($model, 'first_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <?= $form->field($model, 'last_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <?= $form->field($model, 'address')->textarea(['rows' => 6]) ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <?= $form->field($model, 'mobile')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">   
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <?= $form->field($model, 'email')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <?= $form->field($model, 'password_hash')->passwordInput(['maxlength' => true,'value'=>""]) ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <?= $form->field($model, 'status')->dropDownList(['0'=>'Active','1'=>'InActive']); ?>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <?= $form->field($model, 'role_id')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(Roles::find()->all(),'id','name')) ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => 'btn green']) ?>
        <?= Html::a('Cancel', ['/ag-consumer'], ['class' => 'btn default']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Comment: First why are you showing password there better move the password to update password section and remove from update page.

Comment: yes but its client's requirement. so i need to display password in that page

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why not remove it on update at all?

Like so :

```
<?= $model->isNewRecord ? $form->field($model, 'password_hash')->passwordInput(['maxlength' => true]) : "" ?>
```

Happy coding. :)

## UPDATE

If the password field is really need to be there, then try this in Controller :

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    $password = $model->password_hash; // backup the value first;
    $model->password_hash = "";

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        $model->password_hash = $password; // retreive the value back
        $model->save();
        // redirect here
    }
    return $this->render('update', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but it's client requirement so I have to put it on this page.

Comment: Ah... Updated my answer, then.

Comment: Thanks again but I have already tried and nothing happen. even i mentioned it in my question

Comment: @deep parekh i guess you miss some thing, otherwise this answer will work, try to debug one by one.

Comment: Hmm... i'm guessing there's something wrong in your User model's rules. Care to share it, @DeepParekh?

Comment: What happen it i write <?= $form->field($model, 'password_hash')->passwordInput(['maxlength' => true,'value'=>null]) ?> den field is not getting null but i f i write <?= $form->field($model, 'password_hash')->textInput(['maxlength' => true,'value'=>null]) ?> den it will get null

Comment: The problem is in textInput / passwordInput. In passwordInput it is not working and in textInput it is working

Comment: Now, where things gone strange... In my machine, textInput and passwordInput have same behaviour in regards of "value" option. Both will ignore "value" option if "value" set to null. And both will render an empty string, when "value" option is set to, well, an empty string. Are you sure, you could use textInput, and set "value" option to null (not an empty string)?

Answer (score 0):

Dont take password_hash. You have to create new variable in model e.g password

```
public $password;
public function rules() {
            return [
                [['first_name', 'last_name', 'address', 'mobile', 'email', 'password', 'role_id'], 'required'],
                [['address'], 'string'],
                [['role_id'], 'integer'],
                [['email'], 'email'],
                [['email'], 'unique', 'targetAttribute' => ['email']],
                [['created_at', 'updated_at'], 'safe'],
                [['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
                [['mobile'], 'required','on'=>'create,update'],
                //[['mobile'], 'string','max'=>10],
                [['mobile'], 'number','numberPattern' => '/^[0-9]{10}$/','message'=>"Mobile must be integer and should not greater then 10 digit"],
                [['password'],'string','min'=>6],
                //[['mobile'], 'number'],
                [['status'], 'string', 'max' => 1,'on'=>'create,update'],
                [['role_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Roles::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['role_id' => 'id']],
            ];
        }
```

View

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput(['maxlength' => true,'value'=>null]) ?>
```

Model or Controler example

```
 if ($this->validate()) {
        $user = User::findOne($id);
        $user->setPassword($this->password);
        $user->generateAuthKey();
        $user->save(false);
}
```

Comment: even I changed the field name password to password_hash but same result

Comment: This only example of practice